# Rails 3 - Paperclip - Eliminating Spaces inside a filename

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a rails 3 app using paperclip. Is there a way with paperclip to automatically rename all files as follows: All spaces converted to _ , for various app related reasons I want to eliminate spaces in file names.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use before_post_process to alter the filename.

http://www.davesouth.org/stories/make-url-friendly-filenames-in-paperclip-attachments

Comment: this link is now dead.